# Need help with a LOOP statement in a php curl function embedded with XML

Tags: php, xml, loops, sms

I have a php curl script that my sms gateway provided to enable me send sms via xml.The original script is what i have below.

////////////////////////////// original php curl xml code from gate way

```
<?php  


$user="smsgateway_user";
$pass="smsgateway_password";
$sender= "sendername";
$mobileno="2348034057037";
$message= "Your sms message goes here";

?>
<?php

$postUrl = "http://www.infobip.com/AddOn/SMSService/XML/XMLInput.aspx";
// XML-formatted data

$xmlString =
"<SMS>
<authentification>
<username>$user</username>
<password>$pass</password>
</authentification>
<message>
<sender>$sender</sender>
<text>$message</text>
</message>
<recipients>
<gsm>$mobileno</gsm>
</recipients>
</SMS>";

// previously formatted XML data becomes value of “XML” POST variable

$fields = "XML=" . urlencode($xmlString);
// in this example, POST request was made using PHP’s CURL

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
// response of the POST request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// redirect the page upon successful sending

header("Location:customized/successfullysentbulksms.php"); 
curl_close($ch);

?>



/// code end
```

I how ever tried to tweak the codes in order to enable me send customized multiple sms by connecting to a mysql table with the following fields (id,name,mobileno) in such as way that i can select 10 recipients and send a customized message so that each recipient get the same message with his name showing in the message such as " Dear(.$name),thank you for visiting our store today"

From the little php that i know, i believe that i am suppose to connect to the database to select my recipient and then write a "do or while loop" that will enable the script to repeat or loop this function till it has successfully sent sms to all the recipients.

I'm presently stuck with embedding my loop function, please i will be glad if someone can take a look at what i've done so far and help me out.

My tweaked version of the code ///////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="user"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="db"; // Database name
$tbl_name="mysqltb"; // Table name


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Start looping rows in mysql database.
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<?
mysql_close();
?>



<?php  

 $mobileno = $row['mobileno'];
 $name = $_row['name'];

$user="smsgateway_user";
$pass="smsgateway_password";
$sender= "sendername";

?>
<?php

$message = "you have received a customized bulk sms that is suppose to display your name";
$message2= "Dear ".$name." ".$message ; 


$postUrl = "http://www.infobip.com/AddOn/SMSService/XML/XMLInput.aspx";
// XML-formatted data

$xmlString =
"<SMS>
<authentification>
<username>$user</username>
<password>$pass</password>
</authentification>
<message>
<sender>$sender</sender>
<text>$message2</text>
</message>
<recipients>
<gsm>$no</gsm>
</recipients>
</SMS>";

// previously formatted XML data becomes value of “XML” POST variable

$fields = "XML=" . urlencode($xmlString);
// in this example, POST request was made using PHP’s CURL

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
// response of the POST request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// redirect the page upon successful sending

header("Location:customized/successfullysentbulksms.php"); 
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few things that I saw as I was looking through your code that were incorrect.  The main things were 1) one of the $row variables was named $_row; 2) when you are looping through a query's return, you should use the standard pattern `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`, then each row will be looped through, instead you only fetched the first row.
Here is an example of what you wanted to do

```
<?php
$host     = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "user"; // Mysql username
$password = "password"; // Mysql password
$db_name  = "db"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "mysqltb"; // Table name

$user     = "smsgateway_user"; //sms user
$pass     = "smsgateway_password"; //sms password
$sender   = "sendername"; //sms sender name

$postUrl  = "http://www.infobip.com/AddOn/SMSService/XML/XMLInput.aspx"; //XML Post url

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `send_status`=0";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Start looping rows in mysql database.
$totalCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
$successCount = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $mobileno = $row['mobileno'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    $message = "Dear $name "; //Start message
    $message .= "you have received a customized bulk sms that is suppose to display your name";  //append to message


    // XML-formatted data

    $xmlString =
    "<SMS>
    <authentification>
    <username>$user</username>
    <password>$pass</password>
    </authentification>
    <message>
    <sender>$sender</sender>
    <text>$message</text>
    </message>
    <recipients>
    <gsm>$no</gsm>
    </recipients>
    </SMS>";

    // previously formatted XML data becomes value of “XML” POST variable

    $fields = "XML=" . urlencode($xmlString);
    // in this example, POST request was made using PHP’s CURL

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    // response of the POST request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //Might want to check the response here, see if it gives a true, or a 1 to say the message was sent successfully
    if ($response)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `send_status`=1 WHERE `mobileno`='$mobileno' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_affected_rows($result) == 1) //success updating database
        {
            $successCount++;
        }
    }
    // redirect the page upon successful sending
    curl_close($ch);
}
if ($successCount == $totalcount)
    header("Location:customized/successfullysentbulksms.php"); 
else
    echo "Error Sending.  $successCount out of $totalcount were successfully sent";
?>
```

*Note: because this uses your database and sms provider, I haven't been able to test this code.*
If you have any questions on how it works, I would be happy to answer them.

EDIT:
I have updated the code to include a mysql update statement to set the column 'send_status' to true after the message has been sent.  I have also modified the mysql select statement to only get mobile numbers from the database that haven't been sent to yet (send_status is false).
Hope that helps

Comment: @mazzzzz Thanks for the quite explanatory answer,i tried it out and it worked quite well. I just need to do few more tweaks such as introducing a new field called "send_status" and automatically update my table rows to "sent" so as to enable me track successfully sent recipients. I will be grateful to see how this function can embedded into the your answer.

Comment: Re-uploaded the code with the changes.  I would recommend you learn some sql. PHP is a lot more powerful with a database backend.

Comment: @mazzzzz Another big thanks for the quick response, i tried out the modification but i noticed i got the following error display : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/notifytx/public_html/api/smsloop2.php on line 66 . I guess the error was as a result of $row['mobileno'] so i substituted it with $no. This however worked but the only problem is that it did not perform the regular loop instead it only sent only and sms as well as updated a single record. I wonder why ?

Comment: I think it was because I used the wrong variable, because I don't have access to your gateway etc, I couldn't actually check the syntax (without throwing errors with the curl). I updated it, hopefully that will work.  Also, I set it so that the script would only loop through numbers that hadn't been sent to yet, the send_status set to 0 (false)

Comment: @mazzzzz Pls can you send your email address to me at tundeaguda[at]gmail.com . I have some more errors i am encountering but i want to send you a mail with an attachment to explain better. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @mazzzzz. I was trying to modify the code to enable automatically update all the records that are currently set at 0 to 1 immediately the loop ( for triggering the sms occurs) I simply want a situation where the status is instantly changed to sent "1" . I presume that this should a separate mysql function that will effect this.

Comment: I don't understand, in my code, when a message is sent, the sentstatus is set to one